# Angular 8 Material not rendering

Tags: angular, angular-material

My Angular 8 Material components are not rendering correctly .It should look like the example below:
[image: Angular Material Example]

But it looks like this:
[image: Current UI]

Here is the app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   LoginComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  FormsModule,
  MatFormFieldModule
],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the app.component.html

```
<div class="example-container">
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Textarea"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select">
        <mat-option value="option">Option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: did you add material css to styles.scss ?

Comment: example theme: `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";`

Comment: Yes I have,I imported the deeppurple-amber theme in the styles.scss

Comment: can you try stop and restart your ng serve ?

Comment: I tried that just now, same result as before

Comment: what about clearing your browser's cache ?

Comment: Cleared the browser cache and restarted the server but no change

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use   `MatSelectModule` and  `MatInputModule`

Because `MatFormModule` used for `Matform`

So your module should be like this

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';

import {MatSelectModule,MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
   AppComponent,
   LoginComponent
],
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  AppRoutingModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  FormsModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatInputModule
],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

and also you can import css in style.css file

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kfabr)

Comment: I have added the missing modules but it has made no difference

Comment: Your demo is working. I see that all my styles end in scss as apposed to you css. Would that be an issue?

Comment: I have copied your working code over to my app but it doesnt seem to work. Could I be missing some imports or modules?

Comment: Do you get an any exception?

Comment: No exceptions, it runs as normal but is not showing correctly

Comment: Could you control your browser console?Is there an error? And Could you control network tab your browser, does right css install?

Comment: Yes I could, there were no errors logged in the console as well as the network tab

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `MatInputModule` (for input and textareas) and `MatSelectModule` (for select) to your `app.module.ts` file.

You can see what is needed for component at the top of this pages:

[material input component](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api)

[material select component](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api)

Comment: I have added the modules as you have advised but it has made no difference